# In Age of Ultron what exactly did Thor do to Vision?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

When Thor returns to the tower having learned much from the waters he finds that Stark and Banner

> were attempted to upload Jarvis's remnents into the body in the Cradle of Life.  Other team members including Quicksilver (sort of team member at that point) fight to disconnect the cables to the cradle. The Cradle had, while in the truck, a portion of Ultron's conciousness uploaded into it.  Thor arrives and strikes the Cradle with lightning. This finishes the process of bringing Vision to life.

While I originally watched it I assumed that Thor was merely providing electricity and the cables did the same.  In retrospect, however, I don't think the cradle required power in the truck and Ultron expected to complete the job in the truck. Was the battery low and the tower was the docking station or could Thor have done something that I missed?  He is magic...

Comment: I thought there was a shot of the power level, which shoots up when Thor blasts it.  But your "in the truck" argument makes sense, and now I'm beginning to doubt myself...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR : Thor merely finished the job that Tony & Bruce started.**

---

In the film, we see that Ultron had himself connected to the cradle while in the back of the truck. He un-plugged himself before climbing onto the roof to battle Captain America. The rest of The Avengers then focus on

> keeping Ultron distracted while Black Widow & Hawkeye work to steal the cradle from the back of the truck.

Back at Stark/Avengers Tower, Tony and Bruce decide to

> upload the JARVIS backup into the incomplete Vision body. After doing this, they must then supply the cradle with an enormous amount of energy in order to "birth" The Vision. It is this birthing process which gets interrupted by the other Avengers, culminating in first an argument, then an all-out brawl after Quicksilver unplugs all of the power cables.

However, mid-way through this scene as events are escalating, suddenly

> Thor swoops into the room, takes one look, and just leaps onto the cradle and blasts it with lightning. No arguments, no talk - he just TAKES ACTION. He basically makes the argument moot by boosting the power levels of the cradle, thereby bringing The Vision to life. He then justifies his actions by telling the other Avengers that his trip to the Waters of Sight showed The Vision as being vital to their victory against Ultron.

This is supported by the power gauge for the cradle, which was focused on several times during the process and argument, first shows

> "Power Critical" when Quicksilver pulled all the cables loose

then shooting up into the red when Thor brought down the lightning:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok. I didn't remember the "power critical" or "power overload" but they both explilcitely imply that all he is providing is power.  Whether there was a battery earlier or whether Ultron has that much electricity in his body is irrelevant, all that was needed when Thor juiced it up was (probably) electrical power.

Comment: @kaine yep. For all we know, the lightning jolt contained 100x the power being supplied by Ultron before. There's just no way of knowing beyond this one scene.

Comment: There's a nice thematic callback in this scene.  Back during Thor's vision, Heimdall calls him a destroyer, and his lightning starts blasting around killing people.  Then he uses the same lightning later in the film to birth Vision, the opposite of destruction.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about power, specifically, but the cradle definitely required several outside interfaces to function. In the truck, it was connected to Ultron, and could have been drawing power from him directly (along with everything else he was supplying it). Note that when he disconnected it to deal with the Avengers, it stopped doing what it was doing.

> Connected to Stark Tower's systems so they could upload JARVIS into it, until Quicksilver pulled all the cables out.

Again, whatever process was happening in the cradle would only progress while those connections were active; when Thor arrived, he "jump started" the process again, despite it's lack of external connections.

Whether that was merely providing power, or something more mystical, isn't really clear. Given the nature of what was going on inside the cradle, I tend to believe it was more than *just* mundane electrical power Thor was supplying.

Comment: Odin did say that Mjolnir was unrivaled as both "A tool to create, or a weapon to destroy." There's no reason to believe that Thor's lightning is _just_ lightning.

Comment: I like this answer. There is a lot of discussion about the whole "uploading" of the necessary "consciousness" or whatever, and perhaps this is the reason that The Vision is neither JARVIS nor ULTRON, he *may* be a hybrid of JARVIS (since Stark and co were half-way through uploading JARVIS) and Thor/Mjolnir, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Others have providing compelling arguments for the "added power" function of Thor's role. But I think it was also a transfer of qualitative powers. This is evident by the fact that Vision was able to handle Thor's Hammer as readily as Thor himself. Vision is now an amalgam of at least four of the Avengers: Stark's programming, Banner's bio-science knowledge, Thor's hammer strike, and Cap's vibranium embedded into Vision's cells. Sorry. Widow and Hawkeye appear to have gotten short-changed again.

Comment: I think this is the answer I like the most. Vision himself says that he's not just a Stark creation, nor Ultron, nor anything else, just him. When Vision was being printed, Wanda said Vision already had some mental activity even though Ultron uploading hadn't begun (or had just barely begun)--the doctor said it was just background noise, but perhaps she was wrong since Wanda could read it. So I think that Vision still had part Ultron, part background himself, part Jarvis, and part Thor's energy/life-giving-strike